# How can I manually set StartDestiantion for Bottom navigation bar

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, navigationview

I am trying to set manually `startDestination` for Bottom Navigation bar.

there are 5 page, and inside each page there is an Activity present.

So, for example I have selected **menu 3** and the fragment opened,

Now in the Fragment Activity, I clicked a `button` which opens a new **Activity**.

Usually in normal activity when we browse between the activitys when we press **back key** it goes back to the previous activity if we don't set the method `onBackPress`.

However, here after the activity opened when I press the **back key** it opens the **Menu 1** not the **Menu 3**, since, Menu 3 was click before I clicked on the `Button` to open the other Activity.

Here is the code where I tried to avoid for this to happen so, I am passing a `String` key through Intent where when I press the **BackKey** since it opened the **Menu 1** so I am starting the `HomePage` where I have initialized the **NavigationView** and before loading the page I wanted to set the `startDestination`.

Here is my code:

```
 private void navigationInit() {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences= getSharedPreferences("HOME",MODE_PRIVATE);
    String homePage= sharedPreferences.getString("home","");
    
     if (!homePage.equals("none")){
        type= getIntent().getStringExtra("type");
    }else{
        type=homePage;
    }
    
    if (type.equals("restaurant")){

        navigationView= findViewById(R.id.Bottom_Nav_Bar);
        navigationControler= Navigation.findNavController(HomePage.this,R.id.nav_graph_fragment);
        navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
        NavGraph navGraph = navigationControler.getNavInflater().inflate(R.navigation.nav_graph);
        navGraph.setStartDestination(R.id.homeFragment);
        navGraph.getStartDestination();
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView,navigationControler);


    }
    else if (type.equals("drinks")){

        navigationView= findViewById(R.id.Bottom_Nav_Bar);
        navigationControler= Navigation.findNavController(HomePage.this,R.id.nav_graph_fragment);
        navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
        NavGraph navGraph = navigationControler.getNavInflater().inflate(R.navigation.nav_graph);
        navGraph.setStartDestination(R.id.drinksFragment);
        navGraph.getStartDestination();
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView,navigationControler);



    }
    else if (type.equals("profile")){

        navigationView= findViewById(R.id.Bottom_Nav_Bar);
        navigationControler= Navigation.findNavController(HomePage.this,R.id.nav_graph_fragment);
        navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
        NavGraph navGraph = navigationControler.getNavInflater().inflate(R.navigation.nav_graph);
        navGraph.setStartDestination(R.id.profileFragment);
        navGraph.getStartDestination();
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView,navigationControler);



    }
    else if (type.equals("recent"))
    {
        navigationView= findViewById(R.id.Bottom_Nav_Bar);
        navigationControler= Navigation.findNavController(HomePage.this,R.id.nav_graph_fragment);
        navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
        NavGraph navGraph = navigationControler.getNavInflater().inflate(R.navigation.nav_graph);
        navGraph.setStartDestination(R.id.recentOrderFragment);
        navGraph.getStartDestination();
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView,navigationControler);

    }
    else
    {
        navigationView= findViewById(R.id.Bottom_Nav_Bar);
        navigationControler= Navigation.findNavController(HomePage.this,R.id.nav_graph_fragment);
        navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView,navigationControler);
    }
}
```

Even if I change the code like this default one:

```
    navigationView= findViewById(R.id.Bottom_Nav_Bar);
    navigationControler= 
    Navigation.findNavController(this,R.id.nav_graph_fragment);
    navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView,navigationControler);
```

I still get the same result.

The code in each `if` and `else` statement is just redundant to be sure as the code was working.

However, the problem is that the `.setStartDestination` was highlighted and I have checked it says that
**Result of `navGraph.getStartDestination()` is Ignored**

Here is the Code of my HomePage.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".home.HomePage">

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/Bottom_Nav_Bar"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/Bottom_Nav_Bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu_item"/>
```

Can anybody help me out, Thank You!!!

Here is the Image which I am trying to achieve the result when the **BACKKEY** is press but instead it goes back to default start.

[image]

There are two cases here, in first I press the **Green** menu, after that I press the **ViewMore** the activity opened but when I press the back key it goes back to the first Activity.

In the second case when I press the back key it goes back to the previous Activity which is **Green** Activity.

I am trying to achieve the second scenario but when I press the back it goes back to the **first menu**

Comment: Why are you using separate activities at all for bottom nav? That's specifically **not** the approach you should ever be using, particularly when using Navigation.

Comment: You should have only one activity which contains the nav host fragment. And you can manually set start destination in the navigation graph

Comment: @ianhanniballake I am not using separate Activity for bottom Nav

Comment: @AthosTokbi - your question still says you are using a separate activity for each page in your bottom nav. Please update your question with what you're actually doing if that is not the case.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Your are right, I guess. However, is there a way to avoid it. Or do I have to re-edit my code and start from scratch again?. Honestly, I was watching the YouTube tutorial before proceeding with this BottomNavifgatiton with Fragment, and after that I have made some changes in it.

Comment: None of your `navigationInit()` code should exist in an app, no. It still isn't clear what you're doing at all. Maybe consider doing the [Navigation codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-navigation/index.html) and looking at the code provided there will help steer you in the right direction.

Comment: @ianhanniballake Thank you. I will look into it and will let you know if it helps. The thing is that when I use the default code for navigation initialization when I press the back is goes back to the startDestination which we set in the `nav_graph` which is `homeFragment` in my code, the code which I  have mentioned is the edited one inorder to avoid going to the `homeFragment.`. And start the fragment where I left before clicked the `Button`.

Comment: Like for example, I said I have 5 fragment, think you seleted the drinks fragment, now there ,There  is a button which lead me to view all the item which is an Activity not a fragment. Now, when I am in that Activity if I press the back `Button` (logically I should be back to drinksFragment) but I am lead to `homeFragment`. I was trying to avoid this so that when I press the `backKey` I should be lead back to `drinksFragment`

Comment: is there any video related to it, I am not able to get it since I am doing it in android not kotlin.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I don't know but it's not working, when I have deleted which you have said but still. When I press back it doesn't go back to the previous activity. However, I have notice that when I just play with empty BottomNav activity with out any data loading it works but with data it doesn't work.

Comment: I still haven't found a resolution for it.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I have attached the screenshot of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Again, you should not be using activities for your red, green, blue screens, yet you keep referring to them as activities. Please include the code for your green menu and what it is actually doing.

Comment: Its just a section, Like the first one when I press I get list of available food data nearby, on second when I press I will get list of Drinks data nearby. I am using recyclerView.

Comment: I will sent you the link for my video.

Comment: @ianhanniballake You will be able to see that when I press the **back key** it goes back to the start activity. Or if you have any tutorial for BottomNavigation can you please suggest me, the one which you have shared above I was not able to get it some parts I was not familiar with some of the terms. or Can you send like for a basic BottomNavigation of your's earlier one where when a button is clicked or something which can help me out please share, I would really be thankful to you as I am beginner.

Comment: Can anybody help me out,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using the

```
NavGraph navGraph = navigationControler.getNavInflater().inflate(R.navigation.nav_graph);
navGraph.setStartDestination(R.id.homeFragment);
navGraph.getStartDestination();
```

I have used `navigationController.navigate(R.id.drinksFragment);` at onResume method the same code from above.

Something like this:

```
navigationView= findViewById(R.id.Bottom_Nav_Bar);
navigationControler= Navigation.findNavController(HomePage.this,R.id.nav_graph_fragment);
navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView,navigationControler);
```

at main activity

and onResume Method:

same code which I have used above with sharedPreference with if & else which contains only

```
navigationController.navigate(R.id.DesiredFragment);
```

change accordingly with the condition.

Which finally resolve my problem.